# Sustituir listas de un dataframe por valores - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy trabajando con un fichero de datos que en algunas  de sus columnas tiene listas que equivalen a rangos, `[0-2]`, `[3-8]`.

Mi idea es convertirlas a un valor numérico para que me sea más cómodo trabajar con ellas. Por ello lo que he hecho es recorrer las diferentes columnas, y guardar todos estos rangos (listas). Una vez ya los tengo todos almacenados en una variable, miro cuales son los diferentes valores empleando `set()` para así estos darles un equivalente numérico.

Este es mi código,

```
for cnt, v in enumerate(list(set(all_vals))):
    new_df = df_clean.replace({v : cnt})
```

El valor que recorro es una lista con los diferentes tipos de rangos que existen en mi `dataframe`. La idea es sustituirlos empelando `replace()` pero cuando imprimo el nuevo `dataframe` no se ve ningún cambio. ¿Cual es el error?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tienes, es que estas generando un nuevo dataframe, pero el reemplazo se siempre sobre el original, por lo que me animo a decir que solo uno de los reemplazos estaría funcionando (el último). La solución podría ser, hacer un reemplazo `inplace`:

```
for cnt, v in enumerate(list(set(all_vals))):
    df_clean.replace({v : cnt}, inplace=True)
```

Pero, aun mejor, puedes evitar el `for` creando un único diccionario para definir todos los reemplazos:

```
replace_dict = {key: value for (value, key) in enumerate(set(all_vals))}
df_clean.replace(replace_dict, inplace=True)
```